# VBA Excel - Passing Array is not updating the reference

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, parameters

I am working in a function that will read a range of cells in one spreadsheet and write it on another spreadsheet.

To do that, I'm reading all of the cells from a source and target spreadsheet and then writing to an array to compare if there is already the value on the target spreadsheet

The point here, is that I can save the the values inside of the Array, but my functions are returning an empty array. Following are my code snippet.

```
Private Sub UpdateBacklog_Click()
    Dim ArrSource() As String
    Dim ArrTarget() As String
    sourceRead Wks, ArrSource
    targetRead Cwks, ArrTarget
End Sub

Function targetRead(targetWks, arrayT() As String)
    .
    .
    rowCount = targetWks.Cells(Rows.Count, C_TRG_ID_COL).End(xlUp).Row
    currentRow = C_TRG_ROW
    id = 1

    ReDim arrayT(1, 1)
    If currentRow <= rowCount Then
        For currentRow = currentRow To rowCount
            ReDim arrayT(id, 1)
            arrayT(id, 1) = targetWks.Cells(currentRow, C_TRG_ID_COL).Value
            id = id + 1
            DoEvents
        Next
    End If
End Function

Function sourceRead(sourceWks, arrayS() As String)
    .
    .
    rowCount = sourceWks.Cells(Rows.Count, C_SRC_ID_COL).End(xlUp).Row
    currentRow = C_SRC_ROW
    id = 1

    If currentRow <= rowCount Then
        For currentRow = currentRow To rowCount
            sourceStatus = sourceWks.Cells(currentRow, C_SRC_STS_COL).Value
            ReDim arrayS(id, 1 To 4)
            arrayS(id, 1) = sourceWks.Cells(currentRow, C_SRC_ID_COL).Value
            arrayS(id, 2) = sourceWks.Cells(currentRow, C_SRC_DSC_COL).Value
            arrayS(id, 3) = sourceWks.Cells(currentRow, C_SRC_PRC_COL).Value
            arrayS(id, 4) = sourceStatus
            id = id + 1
            DoEvents
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Have you considered using a dictionary object which has a Dictionary [Exists method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251562.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the arrays from the functions.

```
Private Sub UpdateBacklog_Click()
    Dim ArrSource() As String
    Dim ArrTarget() As String
    ArrSource = sourceRead(Wks, ArrSource)
    ArrTarget = targetRead(Cwks, ArrTarget)
End Sub

Function targetRead(targetWks, arrayT() As String)
    ' lots of stuff here
    targetRead = arrayT
End Function

Function sourceRead(sourceWks, arrayS() As String)
    ' lots of stuff here
    sourceRead = arrayS
End Function
```

You were treating the functions like subs that would change the byRef parameter that was being passed into them. A function is meant to return a value so assign the altered array(s) back into themselves. For all intents and purposes, this is no different than replacing the periods in a string with commas in something like,

```
tmp = replace(tmp, chr(46), chr(44))
```